# Mudanças na base de dados com asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, razor

estou iniciando alguns projetos independentes utilizando asp.net MVC 5 com Entity Framework, e mais aprendendo da tecnologia. E no momento me surgiu uma grande dúvida.

Eu utilizei o código gerado através de uma conexão com a base de dados, criando um ADO.NET Entity Data Model (edmx). E ele cria as classes de objeto do banco de dados tudo. Porém, necessitei realizar algumas alterações no banco de dados, como adicionando mais tabelas, removendo algumas colunas e Foreing Key e adicionando outras.

E agora? Como fica o meu código, desatualizado? Sendo que já criei Controller, e views. Há como fazer atualização, ou tenho que fazer as alterações tudo na mão?

Comment: Por isso o projeto deve ser bem estruturado com mínimas mudanças ou mudanças crescentes, no caso especifico, atualize o model (EF) e depois as views manualmente ou exclua e gere novamente suas views. Mudanças sempre ocorrem isso é normal nos projetos até um certo ponto como está aprendendo busca mais informações no site http://www.asp.net/ na parte MVC. Good Luck.

Comment: Obrigado @Maria, e assim como eu estou aprendendo e indo em busca de encontrar a melhor maneira sempre, cheguei nesse ponto, e não sabia o que fazer, se eu gerasse tudo novamente, ou atualizasse manualmente, então resolvi perguntar e pesquisar antes de mais nada, pois meu projeto ainda está no início, mas e quando necessitasse de uma alteração futura, quando já estivesse desenvolvido bastante coisas. Acredito que não ficaria viável excluir e gerar tudo novamente.

Comment: Eu por exemplo @EricoSouza, só atualizo e mudo manualmente, porque geralmente são detalhes... bom eu acho... rs!

Comment: Ah sim @Maria, bem no meu caso ao primeiro ver também seria somente detalhes, não veria mal algum em alterar na mão, mas ai me deparei com o pensamento "Opa, e se tivesse que alterar mais coisas? E se for um projeto grande e amanhã meu cliente querer uma nova funcionalidade...", Tudo bem que não veria mal algum em alterar na mão, mas antes de tomar qualquer decisão, achei melhor pesquisar e perguntar para conhecer qual a melhor maneira.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## E agora? Como fica o meu código, desatualizado? Sendo que já criei Controller, e views.

Exatamente, mais a nível de *Views* do que de *Controllers*, mas os *Controllers* podem ser afetados se houver carga de dados de entidades dependentes, como *DropDowns* montadas no *Controller*, por exemplo.

## Há como fazer atualização, ou tenho que fazer as alterações tudo na mão?

Tem sim, mas essa maneira pode ser um pouco drástica, que é usando *Scaffolding*, ou seja, permitindo ao Visual Studio gerar isso de volta pra você. Neste caso, seus arquivos poderão ser sobrescritos. Antes de tentar o *Scaffolding*, recomendo fazer um *backup* do seu projeto.

Há duas maneiras de fazer isso:

- Clicando com o botão direito no diretório *Controllers* > <kbd>Add</kbd> > <kbd>Controller...</kbd>
- Usando um package NuGet como o [MvcScaffolding](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MVCScaffolding/).

Através deste método, *Controllers* e *Views* podem ser gerados a partir das definições do seu *Model*.

Para saber mais, recomendo a leitura:

- http://www.devmedia.com.br/asp-net-mvc-scaffolding-aprendendo-a-usar-o-pacote/30242
- http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview

Comment: Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: e se eu utilizar o "Update model from database" no meu edmx, Eu vou atualizar os models, correto? A partir dai não vou ter "muitos" problemas ao gerar os novos controller... certo?

Comment: Sim, o passo de geração dos *Controllers* é trivial. Apenas tome cuidado porque qualquer lógica implementada por você que não seja a padrão dos *Scaffolders* pode ser perdida.