# Lugar em que devem ficar métodos de interação do CRUD com o banco em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Estou utilizando o entity framework e desenvolvendo um sistema através do ASP.NET MVC5 porém fiquei em dúvida quanto ao CRUD.

Os métodos de interação com o banco (Create,Update,Select,Delete) devem ser inseridos em qual parte do projeto? Pensei em descrever cada uma dessas funções dentro das classes de Modelo, mas não me parece correto.

Outra duvida... o certo é criar uma interface CRUD genérica para todas as models?

Comment: Olha Cleiton, vou colocar aqui em comentário porque não sei se seria uma boa resposta. Mas, essa interação com o banco pode ser feita em uma classe num diretório dentro do projeto mesmo. Isso seria o famoso *DAO - Data Access Object*. Que seria o repositório genérico de seu projeto. E em relação a segunda dúvida, eu acho que sim, pode criar um genérico para todos os *models*. Mas não tenho certeza disso.

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Cara, por favor, **esquece repositório genérico**. Eu já escrevi várias respostas falando pra não usar essa abordagem.

Answer (score 2):

### Os métodos de interação com o banco (Create, Update, Select, Delete) devem ser inseridos em qual parte do projeto? Pensei em descrever cada uma dessas funções dentro das classes de Modelo, mas não me parece correto.

Totalmente incorreto, ainda mais porque está usando o Entity Framework, que já implementa um repositório e torna esse trabalho desnecessário.

Defendo isso nessas duas respostas:

- [Unidade de trabalho (Unit of Work) com repositório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33280/unidade-de-trabalho-unit-of-work-com-reposit%C3%B3rio/33285#33285)
- [Entity Framework DDD Infra repositório Genérico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40577/entity-framework-ddd-infra-reposit%C3%B3rio-gen%C3%A9rico/40585#40585)

O *Model* é a classe que representa os dados dentro da sua aplicação, **e apenas isso**.

### Outra duvida... o certo é criar uma interface CRUD genérica para todas as models?

Errado. O certo é você utilizar a técnica de *Scaffolding*, que gera um *Controller* pra você com as operações CRUD implementadas por *Action*. [Veja esta outra resposta em que eu detalho isso melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31129/mudan%C3%A7as-na-base-de-dados-com-asp-net-mvc-5/31140#31140).